# Bitwise OR operator in PHP, Bug or Feature?

Tags: php, operators, bitwise-operators

```
echo 'https://www.tehplayground.com/' | '/';
```

Results in 'ottps://www.tehplayground.com/'

Why?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php: _"If both operands for the &, | and ^ operators are strings, then the operation will be performed on the ASCII values of the characters that make up the strings and the result will be a string."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the bitwise OR operator. It interprets each string as binary and performs the operation.

```
01101000 // 'h'
00101111 // '/'
-- OR --
01101111 // 'o'
```

*^ looking at the first character*

**Further Explanation**

PHP seems to loop through each character of a string and apply the bitwise operator to it.

So what actually happens is more like:

```php
"h" | "/" -> "o"
"t" | "" -> "t"
"t" | "" -> "t"
"p" | "" -> "p"
...
```

Any empty string in bitwise operations would end up being all `0`s in binary, so if we just look at the first two characters for comparison

```php
// character at index [0]
"h" -> 01101000 (104)
"/" -> 00101111 (47)
-- OR --
"o" -> 01101111 (111)

// character at index [1]
"t" -> 01110100 (116)
""  -> 00000000 (0)
-- OR --
"t" -> 01110100 (116)
```

Comment: NOTE: technically strings are converted to ASCII first - which is then converted to binary to perform the bitwise operation

Comment: But why it just happens in the first character?

Comment: @GuilhermeCarvalho Basically it will loop through each character (starting at index `0`) and apply the bitwise operation. Since there are no **other** characters in the second string, it will default to `0` for every other comparison. For example, if you change the operator to `&` you will see that only 1 character will be present.

Comment: @GuilhermeCarvalho I've updated the answer to hopefully convey what I am meaning.

Comment: Got it! it basically iterates over both strings and because there are just one character in th e last one, the rest of the characters stays the same. very cool!